# Beautiful Soup open all the url with pid in it

Tags: python, url, parse-platform, beautifulsoup

I am trying to open all the links through pid in it but there two situations:

1. Where it opens all the url ( I mean even the junk urls)

   ```
   def get_links(self): 
       links = [] 
       host = urlparse( self.url ).hostname 
       scheme = urlparse( self.url ).scheme 
       domain_link = scheme+'://'+host 
       pattern = re.compile(r'(/pid/)')

       for a in self.soup.find_all(href=True):            
           href = a['href']
           if not href or len(href) <= 1:
               continue
           elif 'javascript:' in href.lower():
               continue
           elif 'forgotpassword' in href.lower():
               continue
           elif 'images' in href.lower():
               continue
           elif 'seller-account' in href.lower():
               continue
           elif 'review' in href.lower():
               continue
           else:
               href = href.strip()
           if href[0] == '/':
               href = (domain_link + href).strip()
           elif href[:4] == 'http':
               href = href.strip()
           elif href[0] != '/' and href[:4] != 'http':
               href = ( domain_link + '/' + href ).strip()                  
           if '#' in href:
               indx = href.index('#')
               href = href[:indx].strip()
           if href in links:
               continue

           links.append(self.re_encode(href))

       return links
   ```
2. In this case it just opens the url with pid in it but in this case it does not follow links and only limited to the homepage. After opening few links with pid it crashes.

   ```
   def get_links(self): 
       links = [] 
       host = urlparse( self.url ).hostname 
       scheme = urlparse( self.url ).scheme 
       domain_link = scheme+'://'+host 
       pattern = re.compile(r'(/pid/)')

       for a in self.soup.find_all(href=True):
           if pattern.search(a['href']) is not None:
              href = a['href']  
               if not href or len(href) <= 1:
                   continue
               elif 'javascript:' in href.lower():
                   continue
               elif 'forgotpassword' in href.lower():
                   continue
               elif 'images' in href.lower():
                   continue
               elif 'seller-account' in href.lower():
                   continue
               elif 'review' in href.lower():
                   continue
               else:
                   href= href.strip()
               if href[0] == '/':
                   href = (domain_link + href).strip()
               elif href[:4] == 'http':
                   href = href.strip()
               elif href[0] != '/' and href[:4] != 'http':
                   href = ( domain_link + '/' + href ).strip()                  
               if '#' in href:
                  indx = href.index('#')
                  href = href[:indx].strip()
               if href in links:
                  continue

               links.append(self.re_encode(href))

       return links
   ```

Can someone help to get all the links even the internal links within the url and at the end only accept the pid as the returned link.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something but why don't you just put in an `if` statement at the from instead of the regular expression? So it would look like this:

```
def get_links(self): 
    links = [] 
    host = urlparse( self.url ).hostname 
    scheme = urlparse( self.url ).scheme 
    domain_link = scheme+'://'+host 

    for a in self.soup.find_all(href=True):            
        href = a['href']
        if not href or len(href) <= 1:
            continue
        if href.lower().find("/pid/") != -1:
            if 'javascript:' in href.lower():
                continue
            elif 'forgotpassword' in href.lower():
                continue
            elif 'images' in href.lower():
                continue
            elif 'seller-account' in href.lower():
                continue
            elif 'review' in href.lower():
                continue

            if href[0] == '/':
                href = (domain_link + href).strip()
            elif href[:4] == 'http':
                href = href.strip()
            elif href[0] != '/' and href[:4] != 'http':
                href = ( domain_link + '/' + href ).strip()   

            if '#' in href:
                indx = href.index('#')
                href = href[:indx].strip()

            if href in links:
                continue

            links.append(self.re_encode(href))

    return links
```

Also I removed the following line as I believe that otherwise your code won't ever get to the lower area because you continue on everything.

```
else:
        continue
```

Comment: I was trying to use only if instead of regular expression but it started to recognise all the match case where there is 'id' in it or word like 'sid' etc. I was using regular expression because it was matching the whole word.

Comment: That is very odd, but if you are having that problem you should try `find`, I updated my code.

Comment: This is very strange that this is not opening any url except the main url

Comment: That is because the return links has the wrong indentation level, I will fix it.

Comment: I think it is still not working, it is not opening any urls now.

Comment: If you copied my code, please note that `def get_links(self):` was not properly indented, so I fixed that.  Otherwise I don't know why it would return nothing.

Comment: Ok it has started to work now but one new issue found, it went inside the page of say /pid/246 in it and started to dig all the links inside that the one /pid/246 and now it is not moving ahead of that link I mean to the next /pid/247 instead it is into /pid/246/A-Z.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this: please comment if I can improve the code structure

```
    for a in self.soup.find_all(href=True):            
        href = a['href']
        if not href or len(href) <= 1:
            continue
        if href[0] == '/':
            href = (domain_link + href).strip()   
            if href.lower().find("?pid=") != -1:
                href = href.strip()
            elif 'javascript:' in href.lower():
                continue
            elif 'reviews' in href.lower():
                continue
        elif href[:4] == 'http':
            if href.lower().find("?pid=") != -1:
                href = href.strip()
        elif href[0] != '/' and href[:4] != 'http':
            href = ( domain_link + '/' + href ).strip()
            if href.lower().find("?pid=") != -1:
                href = href.strip()
        if '#' in href:
            indx = href.index('#')
            href = href[:indx].strip()
        if href in links:
            continue
        links.append(self.re_encode(href))
```